# Importing a gradle based scala build fails in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

When I try to import the following gradle based project in IntelliJ, the IntelliJ window just disappears.

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies{
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7"
}
```

The idea.log file has the following errors

```
    2015-09-29 15:55:08,385 [77670813]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy
    2015-09-29 15:55:08,385 [77670813]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy in original object too
    2015-09-29 15:55:08,418 [77670846]   WARN - .manage.ContentRootDataService - Can't import content roots. Reason: target module (ModuleData: module ':temp:unspecified') is not found at the ide. Content roots: [ContentRootData: content root:resource=[source_root(/Users/karthi/temp/temp/src/main/resources)]|excluded=[source_root(/Users/karthi/temp/temp/.gradle), source_root(/Users/karthi/temp/temp/build)]|test=[source_root(/Users/karthi/temp/temp/src/test/java), source_root(/Users/karthi/temp/temp/src/test/scala)]|source=[source_root(/Users/karthi/temp/temp/src/main/java), source_root(/Users/karthi/temp/temp/src/main/scala)]|test_resource=[source_root(/Users/karthi/temp/temp/src/test/resources)]]
    2015-09-29 15:55:08,429 [77670857]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.package$ModuleExt.compilerConfiguration(package.scala:116)
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.package$ModuleExt.configureScalaCompilerSettingsFrom(package.scala:113)
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.gradle.ScalaGradleDataService.org$jetbrains$plugins$scala$project$gradle$ScalaGradleDataService$$doImport(ScalaGradleDataService.scala:33)
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.gradle.ScalaGradleDataService$$anonfun$doImportData$1.apply(ScalaGradleDataService.scala:22)
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.gradle.ScalaGradleDataService$$anonfun$doImportData$1.apply(ScalaGradleDataService.scala:22)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:743)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1177)
            at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.gradle.ScalaGradleDataService.doImportData(ScalaGradleDataService.scala:22)
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.gradle.AbstractDataService$$anonfun$importData$1.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractDataService.scala:20)
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.gradle.AbstractDataService$$anon$1.execute(AbstractDataService.scala:39)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.DisposeAwareProjectChange.run(DisposeAwareProjectChange.java:36)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$7$1.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:462)
            at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:931)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$7.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:459)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeOnEdt(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:472)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:457)
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.gradle.AbstractDataService$.invoke(AbstractDataService.scala:37)
            at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.gradle.AbstractDataService.importData(AbstractDataService.scala:19)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:132)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:102)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:141)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:102)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:141)
            at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.wizard.AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder$2$1.run(AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder.java:163)
            at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.mergeRootsChangesDuring(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:328)
```

If I comment out the repositories section in the gradle.build file, the import works fine. Any help in fixing this would be appreciated.

Gradle: 2.7
IntelliJ Community: 14.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in IntelliJ: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9217